# Is it possible to write CustomLoginAction, Liferay 7?

Tags: liferay-7

Want to write CustomLoginAction in com.liferay.portal.action of Liferay 7 GA3.

```
@Component(
    immediate = true, 
    property = {
            "key=login.action"
    },
    service = LifecycleAction.class
    )

public class CustomLoginAction implements LifecycleAction {

@Override
public void processLifecycleEvent(LifecycleEvent lifecycleEvent) throws ActionException {
    System.out.println(" ==== >> >> CALLING THE LOGIN ACTION ==== >>> >>>" );
}
```

}

portal-ext.properties

```
login.action=com.liferay.portal.action.LoginAction
```

When try to login into application debugger is not hitting the code. Do I need add something to my code?

Comment: Are you sure your portal-ext property name and values are correct?

Comment: When I see the source code of liferay for LoginPostAction key mentioned in portal.properties. So I followed the same for LoginAction as well. But, what values you are asking I didn't get exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you should target is the PreLogin and PostLogin actions.

```
login.events.post=
login.events.pre=
```

Hope this helps!